# What is the best complexity to check if an Anagrams word exist in a list?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, string-matching

Which of these two algorithms has a better complexity, if we consider `O(n)` and not `O(1)` for `sort`, `slice`, `join`, `split`? I think the second one is better in terms of performance.

And, do you know if we can write it down in a better complexity or performance.

This is the questions:

```
Anagrams: 
a re-arrangement of letters that spells another word, 
for example: spot, tops, stop are anagrams. 

boolean containsAnagram(List<String> dictionary, String word)

assertTrue(containsAnagram(List.of("stop", "bus"), "pots"));
assertFalse(containsAnagram(List.of("stop", "bus"), "apple"));
```

And, I have written my code in javascript as follow:

```js
const containsAnagram = (dic, str) => {
      console.log(dic, str);
      for(let i=0; i< str.length; i++){ 
          const letter = str[i];
          for(let j=0; j < dic.length ; j++ ){
              const word = dic[j];
              for(let k=0; k < word.length ; k++ ){
                  if(letter === word[k]){
                      dic[j] = word.slice(0, k) + word.slice(k+1, word.length);
                      // dic[j] is empty string and it is the end of the str , return true
                      if( dic[j] === '' && str.length === i+1 ){
                          return true;
                      }
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return false;
    };
console.log(containsAnagram(["stop", "bus"], "pots"));
console.log(containsAnagram(["stop", "bus"], "apple"));
```

Which basically given `O(n^3)` if consider that `slice` or `substr` is `o(1)`. While the actual case is that `slice` or `substr` has the complexity of `o(n)`.

So, I rewrite it using the sort function, as follow:

```js
const containsAnagram = (dic, str) => {
    console.log(dic, str);
    str = str.split('').sort().join(''); // n
    for(let j=0; j < dic.length ; j++ ){
        const word = dic[j].split('').sort().join(''); // o (n*n*n*n)
        dic[j] = word ;
        if( word === str ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};  
console.log(containsAnagram(["s", "s1"], "sp")); // false
console.log(containsAnagram(["s", "psso1"], "spos1"));  // true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are unnecessarily complex. `.sort` is `O(n log n)`, not `O(n)`, so while it's an improvement, it's not as good as it could be.

To reduce computational complexity and iterate over each character in the `dic` and `str` exactly once, make a function that turns a string into an object that counts up the number of occurrences of each character, then compare the object's values:

```js
const groupStr = str => {
  const obj = {};
  for (const char of str) {
    obj[char] = (obj[char] || 0) + 1;
  }
  return obj;
};
const objsEqual = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const [keys1, keys2] = [obj1, obj2].map(Object.keys);
  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) return false;
  return keys1.every(key1 => obj1[key1] === obj2[key1]);
};
const containsAnagram = (targets, input) => {
  const inputGrouped = groupStr(input);
  return targets.some(
    target => objsEqual(groupStr(target), inputGrouped)
  );
};

console.log(containsAnagram(["stop", "bus"], "pots"));
console.log(containsAnagram(["stop", "bus"], "apple"));
```

That said, in the real world, worrying about computational complexity for this sort of thing likely won't be something worth spending time on, unless you're iterating over multiple huge dictionaries or something. Computational complexity only matters with inputs large enough to strain reasonably modern computers.

Comment: Interestingly basically this algorithm produces O(n*n*n), the approach is similar to what I have done in the first solution, just instead of using substring or slice. You are using a dictionary and count the letter which fixes the issue!